# Keep if on object

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

I'm looking for a clean way to evaluate an `object` and return `object` if condition is verified, `nil` otherwise so that I can use a default value instead. Something like:

```
result = object.verify?{ |object| object.test? } || default_value
```

I can see several ways to implement this, but I am hoping that there is a built-in way to do that. Ex:

- Going to the `Array` level

  ```
  def verify?(&block)
    Array(self).filter(block).first
  end
  ```
- Using `instance_eval`

  ```
  def verify?(&block)
    self.instance_eval{ |object| yield(object) ? object  : nil}
  end
  ```

---

EDIT

Here's my actual example (though the question isn't tighted to it):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def currency
    self.billing_information.try(:address).try(:country).try(:currency_code).instance_eval{ |currency| Finance::CURRENCIES.include?(currency) ? currency : nil} || 'EUR'
  end
end
```

I know this is ugly, but I do like the logic of it: if the object I'm looking for exists, go get the next one. The first conditions are existence (with [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try)), then inclusion.

Comment: you don't need that `instance_eval` thing, at a first glance. Why not just `yield(self) ? self : nil`?

Comment: Not clear what value you want when the condition is satisfied. Do you want `true`?

Comment: Very strange question. Why don't just `result = object.test? || default_value`?

Comment: @AlexeyShein: he's probably passing it through a filter/pipeline of some kind. There's value in having a method like that.

Comment: @AlexeyShein with `result = object.test? || default_value`, `result` equals `true` instead of `object` if `object.test?` is true.

Comment: And what about `result = object.test? ? object : default_value`? I don't see the benefit of wrapping this into a method.

Comment: @Stefan: yeah, I thought I saw a reason, but now I don't, as well.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger could you provide a little more context and / or a less abstract example? I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Stefan updated my question. I want to avoid repeating `object`.

Comment: Based on your explanation, it looks like you needed `Object#try` from RAILS,  what was your original question about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the receiver when the condition is satisfied, then assuming that `test?` returns a truthy value when the condition is met and a falsy value otherwise:

```
result = object.tap{|object| break unless object.test?} || default_value
```

Or, following Stefan's suggestion:

```
result = object.tap{|object| break default_value unless object.test?}
```

Comment: Nice. I'm guessing there is no way to avoid having to write extra words like `break unless` in your case?

Comment: You are expecting too much.

Comment: You could even `break default_value unless object.test?` and avoid `||`

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your actual problem - Rails provides [`presence_in`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence_in):

> Returns the receiver if it's included in the argument otherwise returns `nil`.

```
'EUR'.presence_in %w(EUR USD) #=> "EUR"
'JPY'.presence_in %w(EUR USD) #=> nil
```

I would probably separate the actual currency from the verified currency (so you can still access the former one):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def currency
    billing_information.try(:address).try(:country).try(:currency_code)
  end

  def verified_currency
    Finance::CURRENCIES.include?(currency) ? currency : 'EUR'
  end
end
```

And move the logic for checking a currency and providing a default one into `Finance`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def currency
    billing_information.try(:address).try(:country).try(:currency_code)
  end

  def verified_currency
    Finance.verified_currency(currency)
  end
end

module Finance
  CURRENCIES = %w(EUR USD)
  DEFAULT_CURRENCY = 'EUR'

  def self.verified_currency(currency)
    CURRENCIES.include?(currency) ? currency : DEFAULT_CURRENCY
  end
end
```

This also avoids having to evaluate `User#currency` twice.

The `try`-chain can be replaced by [`delegate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :currency, to: billing_information, allow_nil: true

  def verified_currency
    Finance.verified_currency(currency)
  end
end

class BillingInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :currency, to: address, allow_nil: true
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :currency, to: country, allow_nil: true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think @Stefan's suggestion is best, but if you insist on being obtuse, you could write:

```
(object.test? && object) || default
```

Comment: You don't even need parentheses, `&&` has higher precedence :-)

Comment: @Stefan, for extra clarity, though. :)

Comment: Except I don't want to repeat object, because in my case this would mean: `%w(EUR, USD).include?(self.billing_information.try(:address).try(:country).try(:currency_code)) && self.billing_information.try(:address).try(:country).try(:currency_code) || 'EUR'`

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger: yeah, you're heading in the wrong direction, I'm afraid. You need more OOP, not more one-liners!

Comment: That's very subjective of an answer. There is no right or wrong between OOP and functional!

Comment: However painful it may be to add an extra line, why not just `str = self.billing_info...(:currency_code)`, followed by `(%w(EUR, USD).include?(str) && str) || 'EUR'` or (better) `%w(EUR, USD).include?(str) ? str : 'EUR'`

Comment: Wow! I am surprised @stefan's solution did not close this. It is the best solution considering ruby idioms, rails best practices and of course OOD. With this solution, you can simply do:   `user.verified_currency` <br/>

Comment: continuing: When you look at suggested user model:  `billing_information.currency` clearly tells us that user is getting currency from billing information. How billing information provides currency should not matter(encapsulation).

Comment: @CarySwoveland  What change you will bring in your code to handle scenario when `object` is `nil` ?

Comment: @Wand, good point, but there's an obvious solution: assume `object` is not `nil` (or `false`).

Answer (score 0):

If you think you need [`Object#try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) version that can handle default values, you can monkey patch it.

```
require "rails"

class Object
    alias_method :old_try, :try
    def try(params, default = nil, &block)
        old_try(params, &block) || default
    end
end

object = {}
default = "I'm default"

p result = object.try(:test, default)
#=> I'm default
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for [`Enumerable#detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect):

> `detect(ifnone = nil) { |obj| block } → obj or nil`
>   Passes each entry in `enum` to `block`. Returns the first for which `block` is not `false`. **If no object matches**, calls ifnone and returns its result when it is specified, or *returns `nil` otherwise*.
>
> ```
> (1..10).detect   { |i| i % 5 == 0 and i % 7 == 0 }   #=> nil
> (1..100).find    { |i| i % 5 == 0 and i % 7 == 0 }   #=> 35
> ```

So you could do `result = object.detect { |object| object.test? } || default_value` as you've written, or the more idiomatic `result = object.detect(default_value) { |object| object.test? }`.

Comment: Except that his object is not an enumerable.

Comment: Actually, `ifnone` should be a callable object, not just some default value. So your last example should look like `result = object.detect(-> { default_value }, &:test?)`.